# CustomItemReader to retrieve list from DAO

Tags: spring-batch

I have a DAO class to retrieve a set of data from Hibernate.

```
   <batch:step id="firstStep">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="firstReader" writer="firstWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="2">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

<bean id="firstReader" class="com.process.MyReader"
    scope="step">
</bean>
```

Inside my reader, I will call DAO to get the data before read.

```
public class MyReader implements ItemReader<JobInstance>{

private List<JobInstance> jobList;
private String currentDate;
@Autowired
private JobDAO perDAO;

@BeforeRead
public void init() {
    //jobList= perDAO.getPersonAJobList(currentDate);
}

@Override
public JobInstance read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
        ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    return !jobList.isEmpty() ? jobList.remove(0) : null;
}

@Value("#{jobParameters['currentDate']}")
public void setCurrentDate(String currentDate) {
    this.currentDate = currentDate;
}

@Override
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

When I run the batch job, the batch job keep repeating reading and processing.

```
[org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate] [getNextResult] [372] - Repeat operation about to start at count=1
```

Below is my DAO class

```
@Autowired
private QueryManager queryManager;

@Autowired
public JobDAO Impl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    super(sessionFactory, JobInstance.class);
}

public List<JobInstance> getPersonAJobList(String currentDate) {
    String sql = queryManager.getNamedQuery("getJobList");
    System.out.println("---------------------- " + sql + "  " + currentDate);
    SQLQuery query = this.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("current_date", currentDate);
     .... 
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you fill the list within the @BeforeRead annotated method, the list will be renewed before every read

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/annotation/BeforeRead.html

```
Marks a method to be called before an item is read from an ItemReader
```

if you need to get the items from a DAO you need to think about the implementation of either

- easy way - keep the current implementation, but add a check in BeforeRead to init the list only once
- a stateful DAO which fills the list once and removes items for every
  read call
- a stateless DAO with pagination

a better way is to move the data access (the SQL) into the batch, Spring Batch provides out of the box readers for SQL, Hibernate and even more... see http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/listOfReadersAndWriters.html

Comment: If I put this jobList= perDAO.getPersonAJobList(currentDate); line inside beforeStep method, I got No session in such thread error.

Comment: i am almost sure you have no transaction and thus no session for BeforeStep, what is the problem for using BeforeRead ?

Comment: As you explained, the dao will be called on each read, so I was thinking to put it at beforeStep, but I was hitting No session in such thread error. But when I do it in BeforeRead I got no problem with session just it will keep looping. How to inject the transactionManager to BeforeStep? I have defined the transaction and sessionfactory bean.

Answer (score 0):

The init method should be called only once. The correct way to do this is either to implement the InitializingBean interface and implementing the afterPropertiesSet method, or using the @PostConstruct annotation instead of @BeforeRead.

The use of @BeforeRead is definitely wrong and makes no sense.

As also mentioned in the comments to Michael's answers, you should also consider to use one of the standard readers to get data from a db. If you just get a couple of hundred or thousand entries from getPersonAJobList it won't be a problem, but if you get millions of entries, it would definitely be wrong approach.

Comment: Got some constraint must using dao to retrieve. And if I put @PostConstruct or implements afterPropertiesSet I hitting Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException error . Not sure is it my queryManager return null

Comment: Why to you get an NPE? Is currentDate  null? If yes, then your problem lies in the use of '@Value'. Note: if you use '@Value' mit SPEL-Expressions, you need to instantiate org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer as Bean. You need something like <bean id="xy" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"/> in your configurations. Otherwise, '@Value' will not work.

Comment: If I run if(jobList == null) jobList =  perDAO.getPersonAJobList(currentDate); inside BeforeRead, the job can completed without error. So, it should be able to get the value.

Comment: I really don't see, why you get an NPE. But anyway, if you have to check for null, you can do this directly in the read method, so you can delete the init method. Simply put the "if (jobList==null) jobList=perDAO.getPersona...(...);" before your return.

Answer (score 0):

What about add an 'init' flag into your reader? Into `MyReader.read()`:

1. if flag is not setted call `jobDAO` to fill `jobList` and set flag
2. If flag is setted consume `jobList` items.

Be careful using `jobList.remove(0)` because your reader seems not to be restartable; you need to maintain last consumed items index into execution-context so a restart will continue from first item of last not commited chunk.